# Is a Java book enough or should I have to learn algorithms first?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and referring Head-First book.

Do I have to learn Algorithms to be able to make programs in Java?

Should I learn Algorithms first or only Java books like Effective Java, Java puzzlers etc will be enough?

I want to be a successful enterprise developer. Then what algorithms and data structures I should be well versed with? What books would you recommend me?

To be a successful Java developer, do I need to know all the advanced algorithms such as those given in CLRS?

PS: I had C and C++ in my past semesters, I got good marks in them but that was kinda mugging. I know basics of programming. I am not a newbie. Thing is that I don't have sound knowledge in any language also I want to be a developer not an algorithmist.

Comment: What is your programming background? Do you have an understanding of algorithms and data structures?

Comment: You need to have an understanding of algorithms before you implement them, in Java or for that matter any programming language.

Comment: @Raze2dust - you also need a language to describe algorithms in before you can understand them. English isn't so great for this, and the math rarely makes sense on its own. And without an objective test for your algorithm experiments (does it actually work), it's easy to get some very wrong ideas deeply ingrained.

Comment: @Aircule: I know basics of arrays, functions, OOP concepts, searching, sorting,  etc. I am not good in Algorithms. I can understand a algorithm by seeing it but can't make algorithms of my own and I am not interested in that too. I want to be a developer not an algorithmist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to become a successfull developer you'll need to learn a lot of stuff. A main programming language (java) and CS basics (e.g. algorithms) are just two of them. Others are: a communication skills, testing (I'd say TDD but I don't want to start a fight), handling of databases, web stuff, OOD and many more. Also a lot of stuff that you might not use directly will still help a lot by broadening your horizon (functional programming, advanced CS concepts)

There is no fixed order in which to learn that stuff. Since learning works best when you are motivated, just pick what you are interested in most or what is helping you most. Learn a little here, then learn a little there. Keep your eyes open and practice a lot and you will be fine.

In your current situation I'd recommend to pick up an Algorithms book and implementing the algorithms there in java. It teach you java and algorithms.

Also read "Clean Code", "The Pragmatic Programmer" and the SOLID http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod principles

Comment: +1 for "The Pragmatic Programmer" -- a must-have :)

Answer (score 2):

My advice - learn a subset of Java, then learn some basic algorithms, then figure out where you want to go from there.

You don't need to know all of Java to experiment with implementing algorithms. You will need to be able to wrap a few methods (often only one) in a single class (and even that only because Java insists everything's a class). You'll need conditional and looping constructs and arrays. For data structures, you'll probably need to understand Java references, though you may be able to fake pointers using integers as array subscripts.

The point is that algorithms are important, but on a relatively small scale. Data structures typically need a few algorithms to make them work. But you don't need an understanding of larger-scale issues such as object-oriented design to experiment with algorithms.

**EDIT**

From comments, I see that you're already well into the "where to go from there" stage.

Don't forget algorithms (or discrete math) because you don't care about analysis, though. A broad (not necessarily in depth) understanding is a useful resource - they are great for problem-solving methods.

For example, I was recently confused in a dependency-ordering issue about how to deal with cycles. I'd forgotten about "strongly connected components" in digraphs. Once I was reminded, the problem became trivial - no point trying to order within a strongly connected component, but those components form an acyclic digraph. From there, the answer is just a topological sort away.

Knowing about topological sorts makes the last step trivial. Having forgotten about strongly connected components cost me a fair bit of time. Understanding how Tarjans strongly connected components algorithm works... Wikipedia and a few minutes with pen and paper are enough, once you know what to look for.

Actually, I should confess - "I was reminded" means I looked up an old Dr. Dobbs article on topological sorting that used the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you begin learning with Head First. [functionx.com](http://functionx.com/) is also a good site. Most Java books describe algorithms as part of the book, so don't worry about algorithms. First of all learn Java.

Let me give you a easy way to find good books. Always look for higher rated books in [amazon.com](http://amazon.com) and then download them from [wowebook.be](http://wowebook.be).

I recommend "Data structures and algorithms in Java" by Michael T. Goodrich and Roberto Tamassia.
"Think Like a Programmer" are good algorithm-related books.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Steve314 for the most part but wanted to specify some things.

Learn enough Java (or whatever else) to be dangerous. Then the main data structures (lists, stacks, maps, trees, etc), which does include some algorithms for traversing them. Do the rest of your algorithms work after that. Here are some specific goals, if you want them, that more or less mirror the order of [Data Structures & Algorithms in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471738840).

1. Understand Java and OO on a basic level. Specifically inheritance and polymorphism
   (as Java define them) and how to use generics.
2. Have a basic understanding of Big-O
   (how it's defined and why you can
   drop lower order terms).
3. Be able to use, write, and trace recursive functions.
4. Code singly- and doubly-linked lists. They should implement Iterable and support adding and removing elements.
   Use them to implement a stack and a queue.

A couple of things to know about once you do dive into a book like *Algorithms*:

- MIT OCW has [videos lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/) up from the class that *Algorithms* was written for, given by one of its authors.
- The purpose of a book like *Algorithms* is not just to show you specific algorithms, but to teach you how to analyze their running times. You need a small amount of discrete math for that, basically sums and recurrence relations. Look on here for big-O questions to see what I mean.

Speaking of videos, I think this is a way better place to start: [Programming Abstractions (Stanford, Julie Zelenski)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMzH3tfP6f8). I'm very happy that those exist.

(As it happens I am in the middle of implementing a map with a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).)

Comment: Oh yeah... don't bother with Wikipedia for learning big-O. Heck, don't bother with WP for learning any of this stuff.

This is to the point and actually contains examples (crazy, I know): http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: Thank you for giving links of the websites John.

Answer (score 0):

@Chankey: According to me you should take both java and algorithms hand in hand. First learn some basics of Java programming language like what are classes, data types, functions etc. Then learn some basic algorithms of sorting and searching. And, now apply your java knowledge to implement these algorithms.

Cheers!!
Mukul Gupta